# Improving SQL performance when comparing Dates in a -Case When-

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005, case

I have (inherited) some horrible looking (it might be perfectly good!) legacy TSQL code, and i'm looking to increase it's performance.
Basically I have a Case statement where I have several WHENs in that look similar to this:

using (for example)

`(DateTime)ScheduledDate = '2012-04-16 10:00:00'`

`(DateTime)ActualDate = '2012-04-16 11:09:00'`

`WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, CC.ScheduledDate, 1) = DATEDIFF(dd, CC.ActualDate, 1) AND DATEDIFF(mi, CC.ScheduledDate, CC.ActualDate) <> 0 AND DATEDIFF(ss, DATEADD(dd, -DATEDIFF(dd, CC.ActualDate, 1), 1), CC.ActualDate) > 0 THEN CC.ActualDate`

I've tried changing it to actually compare the dates instead of against the 1 (As I thought that running one DateDiff would be cheaper than trying to compare 2 datediffs), e.g.

`WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, CC.ScheduledDate, CC.ActualDate) = 0 AND DATEDIFF(mi, CC.ScheduledDate, CC.ActualDate) <> 0 AND DATEDIFF(ss, DATEADD(dd, -DATEDIFF(dd, CC.ActualDate, 1), 1), CC.ActualDate) > 0 THEN CC.ActualDate`

however a using `SHOWPLAN_ALL` seems to show that the TotalSubtreeCost has increased marginally rather than decreased.

**How can I improve a statement like this or is it already as efficient as it can be?**

*the case/when is part of a select statement that returns either the ScheduledDate or ActualDate depending on the case/when comparisons.*

Answer (score 0):

You could write a user-defined function that takes ScheduleDate and ActualDate as parameters and returns the output date.